# Override an existing precondition in Liquibase

Tags: java, liquibase

I'm currently in the process of creating an extension for Liquibase to support Cassandra. It's working pretty well but I want to add some nice-to-have functionality.

When a changeset has a  precondition, I want to throw something like a NotSuppportedException() or whatever. Problem is that currently, the underlying JDBC wrapper returns a closed ResultSet which results in an Exception being thrown upon access to said ResultSet.

For Statements, I implemented my own Generators. Is there a similar thing for preconditions? Or a way to override the existing ForeignKeyExistsPrecondition implementation? Extending from the class and overriding the check method doesn't work (even if placed in the package liquibase.precondition.ext).

Thanks!

Comment: Most of the preconditions seem to be using SqlStatements, if you implemented your own Database class, you might just not support those Statements?

Comment: Yea, thanks, this would work if the ForeignKeyPrecondition used a SqlStatement, but it's using the SnapshotGeneratorFactory which I sadly cannot override

Comment: Ok and i see, that preconditions do not have a priority like changes have and i am not sure what happens in the PreconditionFactory when you register a custom class with the same tagName. Did you try that? Seems the preconditionFactory does not check for already registered tags, but just overrides already registered classes.

Comment: IIRC I didn't try it with exactly the same name, only with Cassandra appended. But I tried so many things maybe it didn't work. Will try it again though, and post back with the result. Thanks!

Comment: If I use the exact same FQDN, it works. Not a really clean solution but it works. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way this seems to work (thanks to @dag) is using the exact same FQDN as the Precondition I want to override.

Comment: While this may work I found out that this of course isn't the perfect solution - depending on the classloader this may or may not work. I'm open to new ideas :(